# How to load xib on the UITabBarItem click in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I made a custom toolbar and added a UITabBarItem. Now I want to load a xib on that button click. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448207/how-to-load-an-xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the action to that UITabBarItem...and in this action give the name of your xib you wants to load..

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction{

//eg:- is shown below   

FreeSetsViewController *viewController =[[FreeSetsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FreeSetsViewController" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: YES];
[viewController release];

//you will get the required XIB 
}
```

And still if you are unable to get it then please take a help from already asked [How to load a Xib.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder) and also a link that Sam Dufel shared to you

Good Luck!

Comment: what problem exactly are you getting....you had given action to the button??...then what you get after that?