# Inheriting UI components from a parent UIViewController class?

Tags: iphone, interface, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a custom UIViewController class that contains my similar methods and UI components shared by my other UIViewController classes.  I was wondering if it's possible for these other classes to not only inherit the methods, but the UI components too so I don't have to go to each one and add the same buttons and such?
The parent controller and inheriting ones are not exactly the same in UI design.

Comment: Are the UIs of the base and the inheriting controller exactly the same? Do you use storyboards or nib files?

Comment: They are different, I just want several buttons that they all share to be inherited. I do not use either of those, I'm rather new to Mono/iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the view from the nib/xib if you want. In order to do that you can use the method

```
[... initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
```

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448207/how-to-load-an-xib)

Comment: I did not know this and the provided example is extremely helpful, thank you very much!